# Swapping the images to enable / disable DIV

Tags: html

I am just a beginner.
Is there a code to use two different images as buttons to disable and enable . Most examples use two separate buttons but I need to use a single button with two images: one for off and the other one for on.

```js
    $(function() {
        $("#Enable").click(function(){
       $(".div1 *").prop('disabled',true);
    });
        
        $("#Disable").click(function(){
       $(".div1 *").prop('disabled',false);
    });
    });
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link href="css/multitoggle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div class="div1">
            Name:<input type="text" id="fullname"  value="name"/><br>
      <br>
            <input type="button" id="button1"  value="Submit "/>
        <div></div>
        
    </div>
    
    <input type="image" src="assets/trans_off.jpg" id="Enable" value="Enable"/>
    <input type="image" src="assets/trans_on.jpg"id="Disable" value="Disable"/>
   
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: $(".div1").hide(); for hide $(".div1").show(); for show the hidden div  hope this helps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/389/selectors#t=201702231059237385042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use image sprite that contains two button images. Use `background-position` to set what part of image to show.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isDisabled = false;

  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    isDisabled = !isDisabled; // invert value
    $('.div1 input').prop('disabled', isDisabled);
  });
});
```

```css
#button1 {
  background: url('http://images.sixrevisions.com/2009/05/04-31_slick_clean_30.png') no-repeat -80px -14px;
  width: 246px;
  height: 48px;
  border: none;
}

#button1:disabled {
  background-position: -80px -63px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1">
  Name: <input type="text" id="fullname" value="name" /><br>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="button1"/>
  <div></div>

</div>
<hr/>
<button class="toggle">Toggle inputs</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @ArthurKs If it answers your question, please accept answer